# Silex: Set firewalls session lifetime

Tags: symfony, silex

I'm trying to extend the default lifetime once a user logs in. For the login I'm using the security service provider as follows:

```
    $app = $this->_app;             
    $this->_app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
        'security.firewalls' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'pattern' => '^.*$',
                'anonymous' => true, // Needed as the login path is under the secured area
                'form' => array('login_path' => '/signup/', 'check_path' => 'login_check', 'failure_path' => 'login_failure'),
                'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout/'), // url to call for logging out
                'users' => $this->_app->share(function() use ($app)
                    {
                        // Specific class App\User\UserProvider is described below
                        return new UserProvider($app['db']);
                    }),
            ),
        ),
        'security.access_rules' => array(
            array('^/restricted/$', 'ROLE_USER'),
        )
    ));
```

I've tried setting up with the sessions lifetime (cookie) like this:

```
    $this->_app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider(), array(
        'session.storage.options' => array('cookie_lifetime' => (60 * 60 * 12)), // 12 hours
    ));
```

But still nothing. Session removes itself after like 15 minutes or so.

How can I extend the login security firewall lifetime to 12 hours?

Comment: In my project I set the cookie lifetime in php.ini itself

Comment: I don't think its a cookie thing. I've inspected the domains cookies and saw the end-date for the PHPSESSID cookie is 12h. That part is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got it working:

Saving sessions in database seemed to solve the problem.

SQL:

```
  CREATE TABLE `session` (
      `session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `session_value` text NOT NULL,
      `session_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

PHP:

```
    /* SESSION IN DB */
    $this->_app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
    $this->_app['session.db_options'] = array(
        'db_table' => 'session',
        'db_id_col' => 'session_id',
        'db_data_col' => 'session_value',
        'db_time_col' => 'session_time',
    );
    $this->_app['session.storage.handler'] = $this->_app->share(function ()
        {
            return new PdoSessionHandler(
                $this->_app['db']->getWrappedConnection(), $this->_app['session.db_options'], $this->_app['session.storage.options']
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if you don't want to store sessions in DB: just increase `session.gc_maxlifetime` in php.ini.

When sessions are being stored in files, they (by default) get put to `/var/lib/php/sessions/` directory. It's clear that this directory has to be cleared from time to time. In order to achieve this, there is a cron job configured at `/etc/cron.d/php5` that fires script `/usr/lib/php5/sessionclean` every 30 minutes. This script takes php config and gets `session.gc_maxlifetime` from there and then removes files that are older than what is specified in this variable.

The problem is: by default `session.gc_maxlifetime` equals to 1440 seconds or 24 minutes. You can increase it to whatever value suits you, for instance to 24 hours (and limit your sessions by session cookie lifetime).

Comment: Thanks for this workaround! I just don't know if this actually fixed my issue. I believe I changed all cookie settings and none of them worked. However, good to have here another approach in case somebody needs it